# Format a HTTPS call to Google Cloud using simple API key

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to connect to Google Cloud from an embedded device so I have no access to OAuth authentication.  The documents show that I can use simple API key for connecting.  I have created a simple API key but I am having problems using it.

I can test the API functions successfully on https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/pubsub/v1/ but on this developer's site I don't enter my API key (maybe one is generated automatically in the background).

When I try the same command using curl I get a 401 error:
 "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.", "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"

But I am copying the GET or POST command directly from the online API tester and adding my key at the end: 
    curl -X POST -d '{"policy":{"bindings":[{"role":"roles/editor","members":["serviceAccount:charge...."]}]}}' https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/pl..../subscriptions/arriveHomeSub:setIamPolicy?key=AIz....

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

With the limited information you have provided, it is tough to identify the root cause but these are some of the possible ones:

1. You have not used quotes for the URL argument to `curl`. This could lead to some characters which are part of the URL to be interpreted by your shell in a different manner. Characters like `&` are usual culprits although they don't seem to be part of the URL you pasted.

   ```
   curl -X POST -d '{"policy":{"bindings":[{"role":"roles/editor","members":["serviceAccount:charge...."]}]}}' 'https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/pl..../subscriptions/arriveHomeSub:setIamPolicy?key=AIz'
   ```
2. You have not described how you're generating your API key and hence I feel that could be one of the possible issues.

You can go over the [steps for using Google OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) from Google, it covers a lot about client secrets, access tokens and refresh tokens.

As long as you have your client ID and secret, you can call Google OAuth APIs to generate an access token.

You pass in the current access token as the `key` argument to your REST API.

Access tokens have very limited lifetime and might need refreshing periodically. If your application needs to periodically refresh access tokens, consider storing the refresh token in your application in a secure manner.

Comment: I'm generating the API key from the Google Cloud API manager.  The documentation says I can use this key for embedded applications as long as I understand security isn't great.  But so far that isn't working for me.  I'll try the OAuth 2.0 authentication but I think I had an issue with how to store the private key (super long code) in my application (I'm programming in Arduino).

Comment: I'm trying the OAuth for service accounts and running into a different error but seem to be making progress.  See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480882/unsupported-grant-type-in-google-oauth

Comment: @MarkPeterson - I've replied there as well. Please accept/upvote the answer if you think it helped.