# Unsupported grant type in Google OAuth

Tags: oauth, google-cloud-platform

I am getting an error "unsupported grant type" when I try to request an OAuth token for a service account using curl.  I'm following the example for OAuth 2.0 for service accounts (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) and I think I have everything setup correctly.  I have a service account setup in Google Cloud and I'm using that email address in the OAuth request.

The documentation says to use the URL encoded grant type "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer" but it isn't clear if this is the only option for the grant type or what other options might be.

I am sending the the base64 encoded header

```
{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}
```

and "." 
and base64 encoded claims

```
{
  "iss":"chargepubadmin@xxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub",
  "aud":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
  "exp":1497159875,
  "iat":1497156275
}
```

and "." 
and base64 encoded signature

```
{base64 header}.{base64 claims}
```

.

```
curl -X POST -d 'grant_type=http%3A%2F%2Foauth.net%2Fgrant_type%2Fdevice%2F1.0%26assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.ew0KICAiaXNzIjoiY2.......' "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
```

I'm using an online base64 encoding tool which matches the example base64 encoding.

Can anyone enlighten me as to the what the grant type is or should be?

Answer (score 1):

The grant type should be set as `urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer` documented [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests) under the REST API `Making the access token request` section.

## Working example using [google-auth library](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

It will be very easy and simple, if you used the `google-auth` library which automatically takes care of parsing the private key json file, fetching access tokens, refreshing them and actually including them as part of the requests.

You only need to provide the request URL and body, the library takes care of the rest. Here is a simplified example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

# BEGIN CONFIGURATION - change as needed.
# Path to the JSON file containing the service account private key and email.
PRIVATE_KEY_JSON = '/path/to/json/file'
# The API scope this token will be valid for.
API_SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub']
# END CONFIGURATION

if __name__ == '__main__':
  credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file(
      PRIVATE_KEY_JSON, scopes=API_SCOPES)
  authed_session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)
  url = 'https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/<SOMETHING>'
  response = authed_session.get(url)
  print str(response.content)
```

## Working example without additional libraries

If you do not want to use any additional libraries but can use the standard python libraries, here is a working sample (tested personally with a service account of my own) in Python (supports both 2.x and 3.x versions) which takes care of all the steps:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Crypto.PublicKey.RSA as RSA
import Crypto.Hash.SHA256 as SHA
import Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5 as PKCS1_v1_5
import base64
import json
import time

try:
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    from urllib2 import urlopen

try:
    from urllib.parse import urlencode
except ImportError:
    from urllib import urlencode


# BEGIN CONFIGURATION - change as needed.

# Path to the JSON file containing the service account private key and email.
PRIVATE_KEY_JSON = '/path/to/json/file'

# The API scope this token will be valid for.
API_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub'
# The validity of the token in seconds. Max allowed is 3600s.
ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECS = 3600

# END CONFIGURATION


class OauthAccessTokenGetter:
    """Fetches a new Google OAuth 2.0 access token.

    The code is based on the steps described here: https://developers.go
    ogle.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests

    """

    ACCESS_TOKEN_AUD = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token'
    REQUEST_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token'
    GRANT_TYPE = 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer'

    def __init__(self, private_key_json_file, scope, token_valid_secs=3600):
        self.private_key_json = self.LoadPrivateKeyJsonFromFile(
            private_key_json_file)
        self.scope = scope
        self.token_valid_secs = token_valid_secs

    @classmethod
    def Base64UrlEncode(cls, data):
        """Returns the base64url encoded string for the specified data."""
        return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(data)

    @classmethod
    def LoadPrivateKeyJsonFromFile(cls, private_key_json_file):
        """Returns JSON object by parsing the specified private key JSON
        file."""
        with open(private_key_json_file) as private_key_json_file:
            return json.load(private_key_json_file)

    def GetPrivateKey(self):
        """Returns the imported RSA private key from the JSON data."""
        return RSA.importKey(self.private_key_json['private_key'])

    def GetSigner(self):
        """Returns a PKCS1-V1_5 object for signing."""
        return PKCS1_v1_5.new(self.GetPrivateKey())

    @classmethod
    def GetEncodedJwtHeader(cls):
        """Returns the base64url encoded JWT header."""
        return cls.Base64UrlEncode(json.dumps({'alg': 'RS256', 'typ': 'JWT'}).encode('utf-8'))

    def GetEncodedJwtClaimSet(self):
        """Returns the base64url encoded JWT claim set."""
        current_time_secs = int(time.time())
        jwt_claims = {
            'iss': self.private_key_json['client_email'],
            'scope': self.scope,
            'aud': self.ACCESS_TOKEN_AUD,
            'exp': current_time_secs + self.token_valid_secs,
            'iat': current_time_secs
        }
        return self.Base64UrlEncode(json.dumps(jwt_claims).encode('utf-8'))

    def GetJwtSignature(self, message):
        """Returns signature of JWT as per JSON Web Signature (JWS) spec."""
        signed_message = self.GetSigner().sign(SHA.new(message))
        return self.Base64UrlEncode(signed_message)

    def GetSignedJwt(self):
        """Returns signed JWT."""
        header = self.GetEncodedJwtHeader()
        jwt_claim_set = self.GetEncodedJwtClaimSet()
        signature = self.GetJwtSignature(header + b'.' + jwt_claim_set)
        return header + b'.' + jwt_claim_set + b'.' + signature

    def SendRequest(self, body):
        """Returns the response by sending the specified request."""
        return urlopen(self.REQUEST_URL, urlencode(body).encode('utf-8')).read()

    def GetAccessToken(self):
        """Returns the access token."""
        body = {
            'grant_type': self.GRANT_TYPE,
            'assertion': self.GetSignedJwt()
        }
        response = json.loads(self.SendRequest(body))
        return response['access_token']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print (OauthAccessTokenGetter(PRIVATE_KEY_JSON, API_SCOPE,
                                  ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECS).GetAccessToken())
```

After you get the access token, you need to include it as the `Bearer` header in the requests you send as [described here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#callinganapi).

```
GET /drive/v2/files HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
Host: www.googleapis.com/
```

Equivalently in curl as:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <access_token>" https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files
```

Although it is [described here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#callinganapi) that you can specify the token using `access_token=` parameter, I could not get it working at least for Google Compute Engine APIs, may be it works with PubSub, but the `Bearer` header approach has worked always in my experience.

**UPDATE:** As per the [discovery doc for PubSub API](https://pubsub.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1), there seems to be a query parameter for `access_token=`, so it might very well work too.

```
"access_token": {
      "description": "OAuth access token.",
      "type": "string",
      "location": "query"
    },
```

And the [discovery doc for Compute Engine APIs](https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/compute/v1/rest) indicate the use of `oauth_token` query parameter instead and I did verify that it worked.

```
"oauth_token": {
   "type": "string",
   "description": "OAuth 2.0 token for the current user.",
   "location": "query"
  },
```

Comment: I might have to rethink the architecture of my project. I can't find a OAuth library for Arduino but it appears as something like that is required.  How do simple, low power edge nodes send data to the cloud?

Comment: You might want to take a look at Cloud IoT API if you're interested in getting data from a whole bunch of low power edge devices. https://cloud.google.com/solutions/iot/ I think they're still in private beta for now. The alternate example I've mentioned above depends on fairly standard python libraries, so it might be a reasonable option to begin with as long as it works now.

Comment: I'm trying to get approved for Cloud IoT. That seems like the best ultimate solution.  Thanks.

Comment: That was super helpful to me. Thanks. I use Python 3.6, and it works with CryptoDome library (just replace the import module at the top from "Crypto" to "Cryptodome", and it will work just the same). You may encounter some str/bytes concatenation errors in Python 3. Best way to concatenate byte strings is with:  b"".join([header, b".", claim]).

Comment: @PhilippeOger - Thanks for the feedback. Updated the answer with code which will work with both 2.x and 3.x versions of python. `Crypto` works with python 3.x too, you will need to do `pip install pycrypto` if you're missing the library. And of course, you can use alternate crypto libraries like `CryptoDome` too :)

Comment: I needed to `pip install pycryptodome` to run this in 2023.